# jQuery panzoom mousescroll and contain invert aren't working

Tags: jquery

I'm working with panzoom, and it's supposed to work with mouse-scroll. Zooming and stuff works, but I am stuck with this:

I need to make the picture stay in its box, so it won't show what is in the background.

I've been googling days and now I'm turning to you guys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pannutsuumailu</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
  body { background: #F5FCFF; color: #333666; }
  section { text-align: center; margin: 50px 0; }
  .panzoom-parent { border: 2px solid #333; }
  .panzoom-parent .panzoom { border: 2px dashed #666; }
  .buttons { margin: 40px 0 0; }
</style>
<script src="../test/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/jquery.panzoom.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

</head>

<section id="focal">
  <div class="panzoom-parent" width="960" height="1000">
  <div class="panzoom">
      <img src="enocell.jpg" width="1920" height="1920"></img>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
 (function() {
      var $section = $('#focal');
      var $panzoom = $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom();
      $panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function( e ) {
      contain: "invert",
      e.preventDefault();
        var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
        $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {

          increment: 0.3,
          minScale: 1,
          maxScale: 2,
        });
      });
    })();
  </script>
</section>
```

Thanks for your help!

I have made this by a sample https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/tree/master/demo
with the plugin "Panzoom" (you can find it up there^)

EDIT:
This should do it, but it doesn't for some reason work for me.

Contain: "invert" - "make sure your panzoom element is bigger or same size than the parent element.", and unless I'm blind, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but for anyone else who comes across this:

Apparently, this is a known bug of Firefox. You need to include the mousewheel plugin before the panzoom https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too and finally found the solution today, with credits to [this](http://timmywil.com/post/79590637357/hey-i-want-to-ask-you-something-about-your-plugin) post.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style='position:absolute;width:500px;height:180px;'>
    <img id='the_image' src='./images/yourimage.png' />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $panzoom = $('#the_image').panzoom({
            contain: 'invert'
});
$panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
  var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
  $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {
    increment: 0.1,
    focal: e
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like that instead of "e", you should set focal: {
          clientX: e.clientX,
          clientY: e.clientY
        }